# Decorator design pattern with Guice and Modules.override

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Say I have a `StringPrinter` object in my `ProductionModule`:

```
private static interface StringPrinter {
    void print(String s) throws IOException;
}

private static class ProductionModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Provides
    StringPrinter productionPrinter() {
        return System.out::println;
    }
}
```

Now, I have a debugging module that I use for debugging my application. I want to decorate the `productionPrinter` object and randomly throw an exception before the `productionPrinter` prints.

```
private static class DebuggingModule extends AbstractModule {

    // I want productionPrinter here
    @Provides
    StringPrinter debuggingPrinterThatThrowsRandomlyExceptionToDebugExceptionHandling(
            StringPrinter productionPrinter) {
        // HOW TO GET productionPrinterHere?
        return string -> {
            if (Math.random() < 0.5)
                throw new IOException();
            productionPrinter.print(string);
        };
    }
}
```

How can I get productionPrinter object when I override `ProductionModule` with `DebuggingModule`?

See the full example and the comments inside:

```
public class GuiceDecorator {
    private static interface StringPrinter {
        void print(String s) throws IOException;
    }

    private static class ProductionModule extends AbstractModule {
        @Provides
        StringPrinter productionPrinter() {
            return System.out::println;
        }
    }

    private static class DebuggingModule extends AbstractModule {

        // I want productionPrinter here
        @Provides
        StringPrinter debuggingPrinterDecoratorThatThrowsRandomlyException(
                StringPrinter productionPrinter) {
            // HOW TO GET productionPrinter here?
            return string -> {
                if (Math.random() < 0.5)
                    throw new IOException();
                productionPrinter.print(string);
            };
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Module m = Modules.override(new ProductionModule()).with(new DebuggingModule());
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(m);
        StringPrinter printer = injector.getInstance(StringPrinter.class);
        printer.print("Hello world"); //I want to be using debuggingPrinter here
    }

}
```

When I run it I get an exception. The exception is weird, but reasonable since Guice cannot `@Inject` any `StringPrinter` objects.

The only solution I can think of is to use a Qualifier and bind the productionPrinter two times:

```
    private static class ProductionModule extends AbstractModule {
        @Provides
        StringPrinter productionPrinter() {
            return System.out::println;
        }

        @Provides
        @Named("inproduction")
        StringPrinter productionPrinter2() {
            return System.out::println;
        }
    }

    private static class DebuggingModule extends AbstractModule {

        @Provides
        StringPrinter debuggingPrinterThatThrowsRandomlyExceptionToDebugExceptionHandling(
                @Named("inproduction") StringPrinter productionPrinter) {
            return string -> {
                if (Math.random() < 0.5)
                    throw new IOException();
                productionPrinter.print(string);
            };
        }
    }
```

But I find this solution weird. Is there any other way?

My Guice version: `4.2.3`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [method interceptor](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AOP) to achieve you goal.

For your example it could look like this:

```
private static interface StringPrinter {
    void print(String s) throws IOException;
}

private static class ProductionModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Provides
    StringPrinter productionPrinter() {
        return System.out::println;
    }
}

private static class DebuggingModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindInterceptor(
            Matchers.subclassesOf(StringPrinter.class),
            Matchers.any(),
            invocation -> {
                if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                    throw new IOException();
                }
                return invocation.proceed();
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: 1+. I am already with AOP, but I was wondering if there is something else.